# Let $m,n \in \mathbb N^+$. Define an explicit bijection from the Cartesian product $\lceil m \rceil \times \lceil n \rceil$ to $\lceil mn \rceil$.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

**Here's the problem:**

Let $m,n \in \mathbb N^+$. Define an explicit bijection from the Cartesian product $\lceil m \rceil \times \lceil n \rceil$ to $\lceil mn \rceil$.

**My Progress:**

Obviously, I'm dealing with a sort of $n \times m$ matrix. So, I tried to use a few smaller numbers and generalize a "rule" (or "mapping," I suppose) from that. For example, I used the case where $m=2$ and $n=3$ and, so, the function looked like this:

$f(0,0) \to \{0\}$

$f(0,1) \to \{1\}$

$f(0,2) \to \{2\}$

$f(1,0) \to \{3\}$

$f(1,1) \to \{4\}$

$f(1,2) \to \{5\}$

That didn't seem to help very much, though. I'm thinking that I might be going about this the wrong way. Any guidance here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Map $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, and so on up to $(1,n)$ to $1,2,3,\dots, n$ respectively. Map $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$ and so on up to $(2,n))$ to $n+1,n+2,\dots,2n$. Continue.

Comment: I am curious: what does the notation $\lceil n \rceil$ mean? Is it for $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: It is $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it like a matrix so that $f(i, j)$ goes to the $ij^{\text{th}}$ entry of the matrix, then just fill in the values $1,...,mn$ in the matrix.  If you do it in an organized fashion, like $1,2, ..., m$ in the first row, $m+1, m+2, ..., 2m$ in the second row, etc, then the nice formula you get is: $f(i, j)=(i-1)n + j$ where your matrix has $m$ rows and $n$ columns ($1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$).

Answer (score -1):

Each carton can be packed with 15 water bottles. If the number of bottles is 90 it takes 6 cartons.

Let $N\leq90$ be the number of water bottles: Instead of specifying $N$ I can alternatively specify two numbers: $q={}$how many cartons were used fully,  and $r={}$how many bottles are the in last carton that is not packed to the full.
Clearly $0<q\leq6$ and $0\leq r < 15$. On the other hand given $q'$ and $r'$ in the same range as $q$ and $r$ respectively it determines a unique $N'\leq90$.